# Change HTML Anchor Text dynamically using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am using a Geotargeting PHP script on my website to show my visitors different content based on their GEO Location.

I would like to change my HTML Links dynamically with PHP so that let's say users from the UK get www.domain.com/UK while users from US would get www.domain.com/US and so on...

I tried the following :

```
<?php
...

if(Location == 'UK') { $VARIABLE = "UK"; }

elseif (Location == 'US') { $VARIABLE = "US"; }

echo "<a href=\"www.domain.com/$VARIABLE\">$VARIABLE</a>\n";

?>
```

but it didnt work.

How can i insert a PHP Variable in a HTML code block ?

Comment: From where are you fetching `Location`?

Comment: post more of your code.. where do you keep location info? in which variable

Comment: it's just not relevant in this context, i thought.. just assume that the script gives you 2 possible values (UK or US) which depend on the users IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Location is filled with a default country code. Or even better, make sure that $VARIABLE is filled with default UK, for example.

```
$VARIABLE = "UK"; //default value

if(Location == 'UK') { $VARIABLE = "UK"; }

elseif (Location == 'US') { $VARIABLE = "US"; }
```

Also, you might aswell do this:

```
echo '<a href="www.domain.com/' . Location . '">' . Location . '</a>\n';
```

But if it's empty then you would still get an empty anchor.

That works only if Location is actually having the country code information. Are you sure that Location shouldn't be $Location or something? Test that by doing `die('Locations is: ' . Location);` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply Martin !

Comment: Solved the issue, thanks again ;)

Comment: Ah, nice ;) please vote the answer as correct to show the solution to other people having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called as [**GeoIP**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php). Go through the manual. Get the user's location.

```
$VARIABLE = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
if($VARIABLE == 'UK') { $VARIABLE = "UK"; }
elseif ($VARIABLE == 'US') { $VARIABLE = "US"; }
else { $VARIABLE = "UK"; }
```

And if possible, set a session or cookie.